# How do I connect to an online MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am testing a website offline with XAMPP. My PHP code connects and works with my local MySQL database (i.e. 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1'). I wish to conduct tests using an online MySQL database.
I am trying to use PHPMyAdmin [Demo Server](http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/) but I get an error when trying to connect to the server. I changed the 'DB_HOST' to '192.168.30.23' (which seems to be the demo server ip address). Am I missing something?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'ears');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '192.168.30.23');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you think thats the IP address for that website?

Comment: IPs start with 192.168 are [Private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) and can only be access within their local network and are not accessible outside that network. you if that server has a public IP you may use that IP address instead.

Comment: You say that you "get an error", but neglect to tell us what that error is.

Comment: Thank you for the help. EhsanT & Marc Delisle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phpMyAdmin MySQL demo server is not available to test your script. Google for "public access MySQL server" to maybe find one.