# external phpmyadmin from laravel api

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I found this website: https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php. I made my own database there and upload my tables there. Now I want my laravel to point to that phpmyadmin. I changed .env to the following:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=translive
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

but doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: You do not understand what you are doing. Host is sql Server hostname, not some random URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I connect to an online MySQL database using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32870849/how-do-i-connect-to-an-online-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT use the phpmyadmin demo as a database source, that is not what it is meant for!
That website is purely for testing the phpmyadmin web interface and you cannot expect the data to stay there forever.

From [the phpmyadmin website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/try/):

> The database configuration resets every hour. Databases are cleaned weekly, so do not expect that your data will stay there forever.

---

**Update:** It is even impossible to connect to the database from any other server because the database servers run on a local network at PhpMyAdmin. You can see this because the ip starts with 192.168:

[image]

Comment: Just for testing.  how do I do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It is actually impossible to connect to the database server.

Comment: I have my laravel api on heroku. i need phpmyadmin also to be on remote server. and connect laravel api to that remote phpmyadmin. any way?

Comment: Heroku has [a third party add-on for mysql](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb). I supose that is what you are looking for. But you should ask this as a new question because this is no longer relevant to your current question.